# 'eat extra two apples' or 'eat additional two apples'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases, expressions, sentence

Should I say 'We want to eat extra two apples' or 'We want to eat additional two apples' ? OR both are correct? Any other suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We want to eat two more apples.

We want to eat an additional two apples. (a little formal)

We need two extra chairs.

Comment: Just to add to this, the reason "extra" isn't right with eating apples is that we use extra to mean "In addition to what **we have already**".  If you eat the apples you don't have them anymore, so "extra" doesn't work.  If you were **ordering** apples, for a buffet for example, you could say "We need an extra two apples", which implies that you have the other apples already, either literally or in the sense of them already being on the order.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes, that's interesting - I hadn't thought of it before. But you are right. Oliver Twist asked for *more*, not *extra* because he had already eaten his meagre helping. Had it still been on his plate, would he have had the temerity to ask for *extra*?

Comment: If he had it would have really screwed the song up.

Comment: "an extra helping" is used as an expression in books : https://books.google.gr/books?id=K9VjZSNZJvUC&pg=PA43&dq=%22an+extra+helping%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22an%20extra%20helping%22&f=false